# Como obtener valor de una fila en especifica en una tabla con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, html5

Tengo la siguiente tabla, donde necesito que al oprimir el boton "Aceptar" dependiendo de en que fila se encuentre tomar el valor de la columna "Precio", para despues poder procesarlo en un controllador con ajax y muestre el costo total en la fila especifica.

Este es mi codigo HMTL y Javascript

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="mb-3 col-12 table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover text-center">
            <thead style="color:#ffffff; background-color: rgb(33,136,201)">
                <tr>
                    <th class="align-text-top text-sm" scope="col">Item</th>
                    <th class="align-text-top text-sm" scope="col">Descripción</th>
                    <th class="align-text-top text-sm" scope="col">Cantidad requerida</th>
                    <th class="align-text-top text-sm" scope="col">Precio.unit</th>
                    <th class="align-text-top text-sm" scope="col">Costo total</th>
                    <th class="align-text-top text-sm" scope="col"><i class="fas fa-check text-white"></i></th>
                    
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="text-sm" id="list-materials">
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Maderas</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="precio" id="precio"></td>
                    <td>90</td>
                    <td><button class="btn btn-success" onclick="calcular_costo()">ACEPTAR</button></td>                  
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>Pegamento</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="precio" id="precio"></td>
                    <td>90</td>
                    <td><button class="btn btn-success" onclick="calcular_costo()">ACEPTAR</button></td>    
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function calcular_costo(){
            let tbody = document.getElementById('list-materials');
            let rows = tbody.getElementsByTagName('tr');
            for(let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
                console.log(rows[i]);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Hasta el momento he podia obtener todas las filas de la tabla, pero quisiera que al ingresar un dato en el input de la columna precio y al dar en el boton, me procese de manera independiente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varios aspectos que son necesarios arreglar para que puedas avanzar.

Por un lado, veo que estas usando el atributo 'onclick' de cada `<button>`. Para que el callback obtenga la referencia al elemento que la dispara es necesario pasarlo por parámetro, por ejemplo, así:

```
<button type="button" onclick="calcular_costo(this)" class="btn btn-success">ACEPTAR</button>
                                               ^ Ref al elemento button
```

Luego en tu función `calcular_costo` podemos utilizar dicho valor para buscar el `<tr>` que lo contiene y desde éste buscar en sus descendientes el resto de los datos necesarios para realizar el cálculo.

```
function calcular_costo(button) {
  let tr = button.closest('tr');
```

Ahora, para poder detectar los elementos sin comenter errores es necesario poder identificarlos. Esto podemos hacerlo usando el atributo `class`, `data`, etc. con valores distintos para cada elemento.
Por ejemplo, si quisieramos obtener el valor de la columna `Cantidad` sin dar lugar errores podríamos hacerlo así:

```
<td data-value="cantidad">3</td>
```

Listo! a partir de ahora ya podremos obtener los elementos con los valores necesarios para realizar el calculo.

```
function calcular_costo(button) {
  let tr = button.closest('tr'),
    precio = parseFloat(tr.querySelector('input[name="precio"]').value) || 0,
    cantidad = parseInt(tr.querySelector('td[data-value="cantidad"]').innerText),
    total = tr.querySelector('td[data-value="total"]');
  
  // Calcular total
}
```

##### Ejemplo:

```js
function calcular_costo(button) {
  let tr = button.closest('tr'),
    precio = parseFloat(tr.querySelector('input[name="precio"]').value) || 0,
    cantidad = parseInt(tr.querySelector('td[data-value="cantidad"]').innerText),
    total = tr.querySelector('td[data-value="total"]');
  
  total.innerText = (precio * cantidad).toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="mb-3 col-12 table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover text-center">
    <thead style="color:#ffffff; background-color: rgb(33,136,201)">
      <tr>
        <th class="align-text-top text-sm" scope="col">Item</th>
        <th class="align-text-top text-sm" scope="col">Descripción</th>
        <th class="align-text-top text-sm" scope="col">Cantidad requerida</th>
        <th class="align-text-top text-sm" scope="col">Precio.unit</th>
        <th class="align-text-top text-sm" scope="col">Costo total</th>
        <th class="align-text-top text-sm" scope="col"><i class="fas fa-check text-white"></i></th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="text-sm" id="list-materials">
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Maderas</td>
        <td data-value="cantidad">3</td>
        <td><input type="numeric" name="precio" id="precio"></td>
        <td data-value="total">90</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="calcular_costo(this)">ACEPTAR</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Pegamento</td>
        <td data-value="cantidad">2</td>
        <td><input type="numeric" name="precio" id="precio"></td>
        <td data-value="total">90</td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="calcular_costo(this)">ACEPTAR</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

PD: El botón "Aceptar" es prescindible, ya que podrías agregar el callback en el evento [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) del `<input>`

---

##### Referencias:

- [HTML > Uso de atributos de datos (data)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)
- [JS > Element.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)
- [JS > Element.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector)

Comment: Gracias, me funcionó el código para entender mejor, pensé que necesitaría usar AJAX para poder obtener el valor del costo total al ingresar el precio y se actualice sin refrescar la página, pero veo que no era necesario.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es pasar el índice de la fila como argumento a la función "calcular_costo()", de esta manera puedes acceder al valor del input "precio" de esa fila específica. Para hacer esto, necesitas agregar el parámetro "index" a la función "calcular_costo()" y pasarlo como argumento en la llamada de la función en cada botón "ACEPTAR". Por ejemplo, puedes cambiar el botón "ACEPTAR" en la primera fila de esta manera:

```
<td><button class="btn btn-success" onclick="calcular_costo(0)">ACEPTAR</button></td>
```

Luego, en la función "calcular_costo()", puedes obtener el valor del input "precio" de la fila correspondiente al índice pasado como argumento. Puedes hacer esto de la siguiente manera:

```
function calcular_costo(index){
let tbody = document.getElementById('list-materials');
let row = tbody.getElementsByTagName('tr')[index];
let precio = row.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
console.log(precio);
```

}

Aquí, el parámetro "index" se utiliza para obtener la fila correspondiente y luego se accede al valor del input "precio" utilizando "row.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value".

Con este cambio, puedes obtener el valor del input "precio" de la fila correspondiente al botón "ACEPTAR" en el que se hizo clic. Luego, puedes procesar este valor y mostrar el costo total en la columna correspondiente de la tabla. Para hacer esto, necesitarás actualizar la columna "Costo total" de la fila correspondiente con el costo total calculado.

Comment: Hola Inhakinho, gracias por responder. Estuve probando el codigo pero al momento de querer identificar el indice de la fila agregue en la funcion que llama el boton (this)<td><button class="btn btn-success" onclick="calcular_costo(this)">ACEPTAR</button></td>; pero no me trae el indice de la fila o como podria identificar su indice?